# Decimals to one decimal place in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I randomly generate a decimal using:

```
private function randomNumber(min:Number, max:Number):Number
    {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
```

It comes out with something like 1.34235346435.

How can I convert it so that its 1.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can round to one decimal place like this;

```
var newValue:Number = Math.round(oldValue * 10)/10
```

Or an arbitrary number of decimal places like this:

```
function round2(num:Number, decimals:int):Number
{
    var m:int = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.round(num * m) / m;
}
trace(round2(1.3231321321, 3)); //1.323
```

Comment: Genius! I couldn't remember this trick. I actually did that years ago for a problem with memory overflow. Not sure if this is textbook, but great minds think alike!

Answer (score 5):

Just use the .toFixed or .toPrecision method, it doesn't have to be complicated (note that the number will become a string so you'll need to assign it to such or convert it back).

eg.

```
    var numb:Number = 4.3265891;
    var newnumb;

    newnumb=numb.toFixed(2);//rounds to two decimal places, can be any number up to 20
    trace(newnumb);//traces 4.33

    newnumb=numb.toPrecision(3);//the 3 means round to the first 3 numbers, can be any number from 1 to 20
    trace(newnumb);//traces 4.33
```

Comment: I wonder which operation is more complicated - rounding, multiplying, and dividing as in the accepted answer? or casting back and forth between a string and a number, in this one?

Answer (score 2):

If you need Number as result and performance, I would say this solution is more efficient than the Math.pow()/Math.round() one. If you need 3 decimals just change 100 by 1000.

```
var myNumber:Number = 3.553366582;
myNumber = (( myNumber * 100 + 0.5)  >> 0) / 100;
//trace = 3.55
```

demonstrating the rounding :

```
var myNumber:Number = 3.557366582;
myNumber = (( myNumber * 100 + 0.5)  >> 0) / 100;
//trace = 3.56
```

Answer (score -1):

use this instead
return Math.Round((Math.random() * (max - min) + min),1);

,1 will round up till 1 place

for 2 places of decimal you can use 
return Math.Round((Math.random() * (max - min) + min),2);

I hope this helps now.

Comment: That would only return the first digit (1, not 1.3).

Comment: Did you actually try your code? That's not how AS3's `Math.round()` works. It only takes one argument.